# Issue installing cx_Oracle on Linux - Import only works from Site-Packages Directory

Tags: python, linux, oracle, bash, cx-oracle

I have installed cx_Oracle to connect Python and Oracle for programming; however, I can only import cx_Oracle into python if I am in the directory where cx_Oracle lives.  How can I import cx_Oracle globally?  Below is code demonstrating the problem.

Thanks for your help.

**Python Can't Import cx_Oracle**

```
user@T420 ~ $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

**Python Can Import cx_Oracle from the Directory Where it is Located**

```
user@T420 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ ls
cx_Oracle-5.1.2-py2.7.egg-info  cx_Oracle.so

user@T420 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>>
```

Comment: Could you double check that `sys.path` shows `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in it? Mine (Linux Mint, Debian), for example, does not.

Comment: Ah, I just checked that and then looked in site.py to find out that site-packages is not a used folder.  Thanks Aaron.  I ended up solving the problem and will post an answer. Basically, I had to move the files into the dist-packages folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python on Debian does not use the site-packages folder.  You can simply move the files into the dist-packages folder and everything should work.  The other solution as Aaron mentioned would be to add the path to site-packages into the sys.path folder.  However, the python site.py folder says the following:

**Quote from site.py file:**

> For Debian and derivatives, this sys.path is augmented with
>   directories for packages distributed within the distribution. Local
>   addons go into /usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages, Debian
>   addons install into /usr/{lib,share}/python/dist-packages.
>   /usr/lib/python/site-packages is not used.